# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File does not contain valid private key: /Users/x/application.key

Tags: java

Small question regarding a web client sending http requests.

I initiate the web client in order to send http requests with this ssl context, this way:

```
public SslContext getSslContext() {
        try {
            final TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            try (InputStream trustStoreFile = getFileFromClassPathOrFileSystem(trustStorePath)) {
                final KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(trustStoreType);
                trustStore.load(trustStoreFile, trustStorePassPhrase.toCharArray());
                trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);
            }
            return SslContextBuilder.forClient().keyManager(new File("/Users/x/application.crt"), new File("/Users/x/application.key"), "somepassword").trustManager(trustManagerFactory).build();
        } catch (CertificateException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | IOException | KeyStoreException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

the `"/Users/x/application.key"` file looks like this when I `cat` it:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGH...
...
...FhMMXep
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

(Which really looks like a key to me  )

However, when making an http call, I am facing this issue.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File does not contain valid private key: /Users/x/application.key
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder.keyManager(SslContextBuilder.java:350) ~[netty-handler-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]

Caused by: java.io.IOException: overrun, bytes = 111
    at java.base/javax.crypto.EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.<init>(EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.java:95) ~[na:na]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.generateKeySpec(SslContext.java:1072) ~[netty-handler-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.getPrivateKeyFromByteBuffer(SslContext.java:1133) ~[netty-handler-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.toPrivateKey(SslContext.java:1113) ~[netty-handler-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder.keyManager(SslContextBuilder.java:348) ~[netty-handler-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
```

Could you please help point out why am I getting a "File does not contain valid private key" please?

Thank you

Comment: Does openssl think it looks like a key? Try `openssl rsa -in application.key -text`

Comment: Many thanks @Rup, indeed, it seems it is "not" a key 

Comment: 4502449836:error:06FFF07F:digital envelope routines:CRYPTO_internal:expecting an rsa key:x/evp/p_lib.c:300:

Comment: It might be some other format of key than RSA though. I don't know how to detect that: if you can base64-decode the body and find something that will decode ASN.1 locally it should tell you what the top-level container is, or at least an OID for it that you can then look up.

Comment: Try `openssl asn1parse -inform PEM -in application.key`. I'm not sure exactly how to read the output, but if you're lucky there should be an "OBJECT" line with an obvious name.

Comment: 8:d=2  hl=2 l=   7 prim: OBJECT            :id-ecPublicKey

Comment: 17:d=2  hl=2 l=   8 prim: OBJECT            :prime256v1

Comment: OK, great, so it's a valid EC key pair not an RSA key - `openssl ec -in application.key -text`. (I didn't think they started MIGH? The example I've got here is MHcC) I don't know why Java doesn't like it then: maybe Netty only supports RSA for SSL?

Comment: Indeed, I see the key! Then I am very puzzled. Maybe like you said, Netty is not liking this key. Digging further (upvote comment)

Comment: As you are using a password, may be it expects an encrypted private key, instead of a private key. Try using the two argument version, or set password to null.

Comment: @areus If the key was password protected there would be "Proc-Type" and "DEK-Info" lines in the PEM file, which there's aren't in the question.

Comment: no password, still trying to dig around

Comment: What I say is that the key is not encrypted/password protected, but the code `SslContextBuilder.forClient().keyManager(File, File String)` expects a password protected key if the third argument is not null

Comment: Indeed! Tried with "" and null as third password, same issue :'(

Comment: Was this ever resolved @PatPatPat

Comment: Unfortunately no, maybe you can upvote the question to get more attention

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68270058/how-can-i-generate-privatekey-from-nist-p-256-string-private-key-in-android) help? You might have to read the key manually and use one of the other overloads.

Comment: [Also](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/8657) interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`openssl rsa -in application.key -text`

Is a correct way to debug the issue.
The format of the output will clearly indicate if it is a valid key.