# How can I generate PrivateKey from NIST P-256 string private key In android

Tags: android, kotlin, security, rsa, private-key

I have private key in string format. It's type is NIST P-256 and it looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- 
MIGH...
HQ9+...
ZYrJ...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I removed header with footer and spaces.

I have:

```
import java.security.KeyFactory
import java.security.PrivateKey
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec

val privateKeyString = "myKey"
val sigBytes: ByteArray = Base64Utils.decode(privateKeyString)

val privateKeySpec = PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(sigBytes)
val keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")

val privateKey : PrivateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec)
```

Where Im getting:

```
Caused by: 
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Unexpected key type
```

I saw an approach where people removed

-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- and
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

But It doesn't help.
Probably I should use something different from PKCS8EncodedKeySpec
But Im not sure, pls someone help me)

Comment: You should remove header, footer and also line breaks before Base64 decoding. Then the instantiation of `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec()` should actually work.  Are you sure that the key is OK?

Comment: @user9014097 I updated question info. I got some spaces, but after I removed them I got new error `Caused by:  Unexpected key type`

Comment: Did you also remove the line breaks? Can you post a test key?

Comment: @user9014097 sure test one looks like this:
MIGHAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBG0wawIBAQQg0m4yLz+sdzZtBG9QHQ9++wcfq1O4hOWgSBMb/A6eijyhRANCAAQeB0fBl2D7HZOKVBjpPiU2jabzNxQUZYrJ+MSA3LpzZxmRk2JaFHNujjkJghQT19HHjg3Fnkb8Y9oIhB9neXBI

Comment: Try `KeyFactory.getInstance("EC")`, you're not using RSA.

Comment: @user9014097 niceee) thank you so much. Will you make this comment as answer so I could upvote it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234568/discussion-between-andrej-kijonok-and-user-9014097).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The private key to be imported is a PEM encoded key in PKCS#8 format. `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec()` expects a DER encoded key which is derived from the PEM encoded key by removing header, footer and line breaks and Base64 decoding the rest.

Since an EC key is to be imported, `EC` must be specified as algorithm instead of `RSA`:

```
val keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC")
```